# Preferred method for using/writing template with PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, templates

In creating my own template, there seems to be two ways of displaying my body content using PHP and HTML. Which method tends to be the preferred, or **most correct**, method?

**Is there an industry standard? For example - if I showed my code to Facebook, is there a certain method that the person hiring me would be looking for?**

Both of them are clumsy at first to write.

***Method #1***

```
<?php
//Begins with <body>
templateGetAboveContent();

//Begin unique content
?>
<h1>Example Header</h1>
<div id="article_container">
<?php
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($get_article_sql))
{
    ?>
    <div id="article"><?php echo $row['article_content'];?></div>
    <?php
}
templateGetBelowContent();
?>
```

***Method #2***

```
<?php
$body = "";
$body .= "<h1>Example Header</h1>";
$body .= "<div id=\"article_container\">";
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($get_article_sql))
{
    $body .= "<div id=\"article\">" . $row['article_content'] . "</div>";       
}
templateGetDisplayContent($body);
?>
```

In **Method #2**, `templateGetDisplayContent()` would simply `echo $body;` where it should be, between the displayAbove and displayBelow code.

Comment: AS conrad said - it's a question of what you prefer more.
The first one would work faster

Comment: You should look into [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller) and read the [faq], especially the bit about the types of question to ask here,

Comment: Can you define 'work faster'?

Comment: I disagree @vascowhite , this answer can have a definite answer, and it includes code. Definite answer would be yes, there is a preferred, industry standard method or no, there is not.

Comment: He can't. it's merely a superstition.

Comment: faster = less computing operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any programming language is built to give flexibility to the developer. They're just "toolkits" provided to programmers and it's up to the programmers to implement stuff (and invent stuff) they want done. As far as i know, there are a lot of templating engines (both built in to frameworks and standalones) out there that simplify rendering of pages but sacrifice that flexibility for the ease of use.

You mention Facebook (and surely figured out they use PHP). However, what you don't know is that they have developers that build their own API which may include templating for their pages - in other words, their own implementation.

All in all, it depends on what you are going to do and what tools you use at the moment. You should try exploring using frameworks and other tools. You will learn a lot on how each of them implement their templating methods (sooner or later you will lean to one or two of these methods).

personal suggestion: try [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Both methods apparently has nothing to do with *templates* at all.
First one is closer but seeing a word "mysql" in the *template* one can say that is failed attempt for sure.

You have to make a strict separation between data processing part and data displaying part.
There should be not a single symbol sent to the browser until all data got ready.

So, make your site consists of pages, page templates and main template.
Once your script called, it have to process data, and then load site template, which, in turn, will load page template.

An example layout is going to be like this:
a page:

```
<?
//include our settings, connect to database etc.
include dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/cfg/settings.php';
//getting required data
$DATA=dbgetarr("SELECT * FROM links");
$pagetitle = "Links to friend sites";
//etc
//and then call a template:
$tpl = "links.tpl.php";
include "template.php";
?>
```

it outputs **nothing** but only gather required data and calls a template:

`template.php` which is your main site template,

consists of your err.. templateGetAboveContent() and templateGetBelowContent():

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>My site. <?=$pagetitle?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<? include $tpl ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and calls the actual page template:

```
<h2><?=$pagetitle?></h2>
<ul>
<? foreach($DATA as $row): ?>
<li><a href="<?=$row['link']?>" target="_blank"><?=$row['name']?></a></li>
<? endforeach ?>
<ul>
```

This would be a REAL use of templates.

Note that the main site template is able to display variable texts depends on the current page contents.

> Is there an industry standard?

No. There are several standards.
Escaping from HTML is closer to one of them, but still you are using it wrong way.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough answer, but for simplicities sake, you're only seeing the body content part of the template. It appears from your answer that you are saying method #1 is the preferred method, correct?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a 100% correct answer to this, as both will ultimately get you the goal you need.

Using Method 1 though will likely allow you to better interact with the templates in the event they need to be updated.

Especially if another party like a designer is involved, who is providing static HTML.

You could easily go into that and just add the PHP tags/code where need be.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I think the first example is simple and straight to the point. And I think someone who would be hiring you would think the same. Plus, keeping all the body content in a variable would be a hassle to use across a whole site.